# Model property not populated from form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my entity class:

```
class Locker
{
    public string FrontColor { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfigureFurniture", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

 <input type="color" name="FrontColor" id="color1"/>


 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Zamów" />

}
```

In the POST action the property on my model is not populated.

```
public ActionResult ConfigureFurniture()
{
    var furnitureViewModel = _furnitureService.GetFurnitureViewModel();

    return View(furnitureViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfigureFurniture(FurnitureViewModel furnitureViewModel)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

FurnitureViewModel and Locker class are the same inside

Comment: Please show your `ConfigureFurniture` method.

Comment: Just a warning...  `<input type="color">` is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 and older.

Comment: What is `Color`? Is that the `System.Drawing.Color` struct? (in which case this will not work and it needs to be `string FrontColor` unless you create a `ValueProvider`)

Comment: It doesn't have to be Color type in model, can be a string, but I am still getting null returner in Post action, when I choose color in form.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only class you've posted is `Locker`, which has the property, `FrontColor`, you're trying to set. However, your action takes `FurnitureViewModel`, the code for which you have not included in your question. However, based on this, I can guess the problem. Most likely you have something like:

```
public class FurnitureViewModel
{
    ...

    public Locker Locker { get; set; }
}
```

That means, in order for the model binder to bind the value, it needs it posted as `Locker.FrontColor`, *not* just `FrontColor`:

```
<input type="color" name="Locker.FrontColor" id="color1" />
```

Or, better, just use the helpers, as they'll generate the right names for you:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Locker.FrontColor, new { type = "color" })
```

Additionally, you'll need to keep `FrontColor` typed as `string`. As @Fran correctly pointed out, you cannot bind directly to `Color`.

Comment: You are a genius !
Thanks a lot! I spent like several hours with that.. ;(

Answer (score 1):

The selected `FrontColor` is most likely send as a string with a value of `"#00ff00"` or similar but you can confirm the exact value inspecting your header of the post event in your browser debugger.

You could change the type to a string.

```
class Data{
    public string SelectedColor { get; set; }
}
```

Rename your input

```
<input type="color" name="SelectedColor" id="color1"/>
```

Then you could add a support property or method to your `data` class to return the color type based on the hex string

Assuming the string you get is a hex value like `#ffffff` you could use [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
class Data{
    public string SelectedColor { get; set; }

    public Color FrontColor() {
        return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(SelectedColor);
    }
}
```

You can see a working .NET Fiddle demo of using `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` [**here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6NrJPQ)

Comment: I changed type to string, I still get null returned.

Comment: When you do the post, while having the network tab open in the browser debugger console (F12 in Chrome) what value do you see is being posted in the header of the request? You should see the form data values being posted there.

Comment: #66ecec - so it get's data read..
But in post method while debuggind application, property Frontcolor (string type) get's null...

Comment: What does your action `ConfigureFurniture` look like?

Comment: If `FurnitureViewModel` contains a string property of `string FrontColor {get; set;}` , the post data shows `{FrontColor: #66ecec}` is sent and your breakpoint in the `[HttpPost]ConfigureFurniture` action is hit then I don't know :( That is standard implementation that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The controller action which you're POSTing the data to expects a value of type `Color`, defined in C#. I don't know if that type is one that you've created or just `System.Drawing.Color`

Anyway, the problem is that your input `<input type="color" ...` does not create a value of the type that C# requires, so the data comes through as `null`.

Comment: I can get string as data type in my model, doesnt matter..
I am still getting null value

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Color class properties like this;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Color.xx, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Color.yy, new { @class = "form-control" })
```